# Zend pagination and routing

Tags: php, zend-framework

Having a bit of trouble getting my URLs to work properly.

The URL looks like this: /messages/from/1/page/5

My route looks like this

```
$router->addRoute('messages-from',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('messages/from/:user_id/:page', array(
    'controller' => 'messages',
    'action' => 'from',
    'page' => 1
))
);
```

Which works fine. But the URL is missing the /page/ part. If I add it in:

```
'messages/from/:user_id/page/:page'
```

then it breaks and the user_id param is always null.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: When you catch the request in your controller like so: `die(var_dump($this->getRequest()));`, what does that return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to be able to leave off the `/page/` part from the URL, you would have to define two separate routes, one that matches the user ID and page parameters and one that only matches the user ID without the page so the router can find route matches in both cases.

Alternatively, this [`regex`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) based route works in both cases.

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'messages/from/(\d+)(?:/page/(\d+)/?)?',
    array(
        'controller' => 'messages',
        'action'     => 'from',
        'page'       => 1,
    ),
    array(
        1 => 'from',
        2 => 'page',
    )
);

$router->addRoute('messages-from', $route);
```

Based on the URL you supplied, I assumed in the regex that the `from` parameter is an integer.  If you can have strings passed, you will need to change the `(\d+)` pattern to something more suitable like `([\w\d_-\.]+)`.